# Toast current location in Navigation Drawer Activity action bar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

so I have a `Navigation Drawer Activity (a non activity class)`. There is a button (on the action bar) that should `Toast` current location in `Latitude` and `Longitude` but I couldn't get the `getsystemservice()` to work in the `Navigation Drawer Activity`.

Below is the code.

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.current_location) {
            //TODO FInd a way to receive location info
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
            if (location != null){

            }

            String Text = "Current Location: \n" +
                "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n" +
                "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So at `getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` it keeps telling me that the method is not resolved while it is perfectly fine in a Main.java activity.

How could I get the latitude and longitude to work in the drawer activity? 
is there an easier way to code this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. If its ur non activity class then you should give a content reference to call that. Like `context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **getActivity()**.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you work with fragments in android, you should use the method `getActivity()` to get the context ( all fragments depends on an activity) , so as posted in the comment above, you must use the method `getActivity()`.